# WebView is not showing gmail messages

Tags: android, webview, gmail

I'm trying to create a application to access a gmail account.
I used a WebView with a WebViewClient and load the url http://www.gmail.com. See code below

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.email_main_layout);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new EmailWebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.gmail.com");
}
```

The site loads normally. However, after loged in, the emails messagens are not shown, only a progress loading appears and other options.
Since I can use gmail in android browser, what settings I have to do in my webview to show gmail correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It was missing set DOM storage in webview property

```
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```